# Pandas long to wide form

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a long dataframe with an index of a timeseries like this:

```
datetime             number
2015-07-06 00:00:00  12
2015-07-06 00:10:00  55
2015-07-06 00:20:00  129
2015-07-06 00:30:00  5
2015-07-06 00:40:00  3017
2015-07-06 00:50:00  150
2015-07-06 01:00:00  347
2015-07-06 01:10:00  8
2015-07-06 01:20:00  19
...                  ...
```

I would like to transform/reshape this by splitting the column every n rows into a row in a 'new' table.

For example, an n=3 create:

```
datetime             #0    #1    #2
2015-07-06 00:00:00  12    55    129
2015-07-06 00:30:00  5     3017  150
2015-07-06 01:00:00  347   8     19
...                  ...   ...   ...
```

I can think of doing this with a For-Loop, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way native to Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `apply`/`agg` with `list`:

```
u = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='30min'))['number'].agg(list)
pd.DataFrame(u.tolist(), index=u.index)

                       0     1    2
datetime                           
2015-07-06 00:00:00   12    55  129
2015-07-06 00:30:00    5  3017  150
2015-07-06 01:00:00  347     8   19
```

Comment: This gives a KeyError of 'The grouper name datetime is not found'

Comment: I solved this issue by removing the key from the arguments:
    u = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min'))['number'].agg(list)
    pd.DataFrame(u.tolist(), index=u.index)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution

```
n = 3
new_df = df.groupby(df.index//n).agg({'datetime': 'first', 'number': lambda x: x.tolist()})
new_df.assign(**(new_df.number.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('#')))


    datetime            number          #0  #1      #2
0   2015-07-06 00:00:00 [12, 55, 129]   12  55      129
1   2015-07-06 00:30:00 [5, 3017, 150]  5   3017    150
2   2015-07-06 01:00:00 [347, 8, 19]    347 8        19
```

You can drop the number column

Edit: As @coldspeed suggested, you can combine the last two steps.

```
new_df = df.groupby(df.index//n).agg({'datetime': 'first', 'number': lambda x: x.tolist()})
new_df.assign(**(new_df.pop('number').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('#')))

    datetime            #0  #1      #2
0   2015-07-06 00:00:00 12  55      129
1   2015-07-06 00:30:00 5   3017    150
2   2015-07-06 01:00:00 347 8       19
```

Comment: You can drop and assign in one step if you use df.pop("number").apply(...)... :)

Comment: This gives me a TypeError of "cannot perform \_\_floordiv\_\_ with this index type: DatetimeIndex"